# Separation of variables and inequality

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

I need to separate variables x, w and y,z to obtain in the right hand of inequality the product of two linear form with x and w in one hand and y and z in the other hand: 
Assume 
$\alpha \leq 0$,  $x, w\in \mathbb{R} $ and $y, z \in (0,1) $ 
$\vert x\sqrt{y}-w\sqrt{z}\vert ^{\alpha} \leq F(x,w)G(y,z)$

Any ideas of type of inequality i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

CS inequality would give you
$$|x\sqrt y - w \sqrt z|^2 \leqslant (x^2+w^2)(y + z)$$
$$\implies |x\sqrt y - w \sqrt z|^\alpha \leqslant (x^2+w^2)^{\alpha/2}(y + z)^{\alpha/2}$$

Comment: Do you apply CS to what ?

Comment: @nour  Have added a line, hopefully you can make out now.